# How to make eager loading with some relation tables

Tags: laravel

I am using laravel 9 for my project with relation some tables

| table types | genders | qualifications | occupations |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| id | id | id | id |
| name | name | name | name |

| mains | members | pivot table : main_member |
| --- | --- | --- |
| id | id | id |
| type_id | main_id | main_id |
| full_name | full_name | member_id |
| address |  |  |

Models : Type (relation with table mains)

```
public function mains()
{
   return $this->hasMany(Main::class);
}
```

Models : Gender (relation with table members)

```
public function member()
{
   return $this->hasMany(Member::class);
}
```

Models : Qualification (relation with table members)

```
public function member()
{
   return $this->hasMany(Member::class);
}
```

Models : Occupation (relation with table members)

```
public function member()
{
   return $this->hasMany(Member::class);
}
```

Models : Occupation (relation with table members)

```
public function member()
{
   return $this->hasMany(Member::class);
}
```

-- belongToMany relation --

Models : Main (relation with table members)

```
public function members()
{
   return $this->belongsToMany(Member::class)
}
```

I have already create controller : MainController

```
public function index()
{
   $this->data['warga'] = Main::with('members')->get();
   $this->data['title'] = 'Family list';
   return $this->adminTheme('family.index', $this->data);
}
```

With code above, I can retrieve record from table mains and also table members inside table mains.

The problem that I found is there are hundreds query at the same times (with 50 samples data in table mains and almost 100 datas in table members).

How can I implement eager loading to minimize query above.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: instead of query on each model make relations in your main model then use ``Main::with(['relations'])->get()``... if not solved add your view code for table. and i believe you should've given foreign keys as well for table relations.

Comment: Thank you, I have already gives foreign key for all my tables. Now I can get less than 20 queries with my case above. And also I have already left comment in last answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

How about pagination?

```
Main::with('members')->paginate()
```

Comment: Thank you, unfortunatelly, they still 224 queries with paginate(), it's also same total queries with get().

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this

```
Main::with('members' => function ($q) {
    // the realation you want, you can eager load from here
    // I am not sure if gender is in member model, its just for
    // example, you can adjust your relationship        
    $q->with('gender');  
})->get()
```

Comment: Thank you all. I found and follow instructions of [link]https://github.com/ajcastro/eager-load-pivot-relations and it's work for me. Now I get less than 20 queries for above case. Again thank you all for your help and assistance.